# THREE js Object location not updating on rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to create a solar system model using three js for last two weeks. I have followed som tutorials and documentations. I have created a model of the solar system which is working fine as it is. Now I want the camera to zoom on to a planet when it is clicked. The code is working fine for the sun as it is not moving from its position, but for the planets revolving around the sun, it can detect which planet i have clicked on (I am uisng object.name to check), it always zooms to the planets starting position which is empty.
I am creating the orbiting/revolution simulation by creating invisible parent for each planet at sun's position and then rotating it(parent.rotatey in animate()). Hence the planet revolution is working fine but planet.position does not changes. I have tried **update matrix** function, still to no avail.

I created this func that takes in intitial position of the planet,distance between sun/parent to planet,angular speed(rotation speed for respective parent) and number of times the rotatey function was called in animate(). I dont know but I think the problem is in this function or may be my way of handling this problem.
Looking for help in correcting this func or if there is any other way of getting position of the object.
I am using TWEEN animation to move camera from current location to closer to the object's location.

```
function calculateCurrentPosition(initialPos, distance, angularSpeed, time) {
    console.log(initialPos, distance, angularSpeed, time);
    if (time === 0) {
        return initialPos;
    }
    var currentAngle = angularSpeed * time;
    var currentX = initialPos.x + distance * Math.cos(currentAngle);
    var currentZ = initialPos.z + distance * Math.sin(currentAngle);
    return { x: currentX, y: initialPos.y, z: currentZ };
}
```

The movement is along x-z plane therefore y is constant.

The code for creating the planet object is:

```
function createPlanete(size, texture, position, ring) {
    const geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 30, 30);
    const mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: textureLoader.load(texture)
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    const obj = new THREE.Object3D();
    obj.add(mesh);
    if(ring) {
        const ringGeo = new THREE.RingGeometry(
            ring.innerRadius,
            ring.outerRadius,
            32);
        const ringMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: textureLoader.load(ring.texture),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        const ringMesh = new THREE.Mesh(ringGeo, ringMat);
        obj.add(ringMesh);
        ringMesh.position.x = position;
        ringMesh.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
    }
    scene.add(obj);
    mesh.position.x = position;
    return {mesh, obj}
}
```

Tell me if you require anything else regarding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup as I doubted, I was handling it the wrong way. I simply used `obj.parent.children[0].getWorldPosition(target);`
and it solves the problem. It gets the position of the child and saves it in target variable.
Here obj is the object I have clicked on(A planet object in this case). The parent is parent of the planet, whose rotation mimics the orbiting.